# 'ignore.malformed.json'='true' is set in AWS Glue table, however Athena, still gives JSON Object - JSONException: error

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to query JSON files on S3 from Athena, however, some of the JSON objects are incomplete/have some error. In accordance with the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html#openxjson) I have set:

```
'ignore.malformed.json'='true' 
serde = org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
```

[image]

However, I stil get JSON exceptions while querying them with Athena.
Could some one help?

Here is the structure of the DDL.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test2_v2 (
  message string, 
  version int, 
  equipmentnumber string, 
  anyequip struct
                 < 
                  aehdversion:string,
                  aemanufacture:string,
                  aeswversion:string,
                  anyequipid:string 
                  > 
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  year string, 
  month string, 
  day string, 
  hour string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'ignore.malformed.json'='true') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://kafkamessages/topics/abc/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='test_table', 
  'averageRecordSize'='1445', 
  'classification'='json', 
  'compressionType'='gzip', 
  'objectCount'='1393', 
  'recordCount'='442738', 
  'sizeKey'='560050710', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Error message is as below

```
Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Unterminated string at 20481 [character 20482 line 1]
```

Regards,
RR

Comment: Could you provide the table DDL, i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name` as well as the exact exception you are getting, please?)

Comment: have added the details

Comment: goto jsonlint.com and check if data is as per syntax. Otherwise it will throw error

Comment: It is not as per the syntax , the JSON is malformed, but the property ignore.malformed.json is set to true. Shouldn’t it then return them as null rows and not throw and error?

Comment: can you post the JSON record in question?

Answer (score 1):

Reach out to AWS Support and request them to help you identify the S3 file causing this error.

Once in this data file, run a regex search for a line with opening and closing braces in a single line - In my case I used the Find option in Sublime Text (with regex enabled) and searched for **{ .* }**

- Even with **ignore.malformed.json**, the SerDe will only discard lines in data files that it cannot singularly parse as a valid JSON block.
- Chances are that even with a data file having JSON records saved in a multi-line format, one of the inner JSON blocks might have the opening bracket, content, and closing bracket in a single line.
- If this is the case, then the SerDe will not ignore this line and instead treat is as a valid JSON record.

Example 1: This will print 5 empty lines when ignore.malformed.json is set to TRUE.

```
{
    "fruit": "Mango",
    "traits":[{
         "size": "Large",
         "color": "Yellow"
    }]
}
```

Example 2: This will try to parse line #4 according to table schema, and return an error if query:

```
{
    "fruit": "Mango",
    "traits":[
         {"size": "Large","color": "Yellow"}
    ]
}
```